# checkbox is not checked through each() when I click it

Tags: jquery, select, checkbox

I've checked many questions here beside to .prop() attribute, but nothing gained. I have an input as below:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_ignore_few[]" class="chk_ignore_few">
```

And another as below:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_ignore_all" id="chk_ignore_all">
```

And this is my code:

```
$('#chk_ignore_all').click(function() {
    $('.chk_ignore_few').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
    });
});
```

I checked it with firebug, and saw that it loops through different checkboxes, but it doesn't check them at all. What is my problem above?

```
                      =============**EDIT**=====================
```

The problem was that in the project jQuery UI has been used and I was unaware of that. The actual checkbox was hidden behind pictures and checkboxes opacity was 0. Is there a way to trigger checked in jQuery UI?

Comment: try: `$('.chk_ignore_few').prop('checked', true);` without using useless each() loop. And don't you wish to use onchange event instead of onclick and then check for element #chk_ignore_all checked or not?

Comment: Please, provide a jsfiddle, i don't know how jquery UI could badly interact with any native checkbox element

Comment: jQuery uniform was used. To solve the problem I just added no-data-uniform="true" to all checkboxes and everything now is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `prop()` and do not use `attr()`, you do not need `each()`

```
$('.chk_ignore_few').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) instead of `attr()` and no need to use `each()` like,

```
$('#chk_ignore_all').click(function() {
    $('.chk_ignore_few').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RLt36/)

Comment: I'd use change event instead, better for handling older browser where state of checkbox could be set after click event

Comment: What older browsers? I have only EVER used click since change needs a blur in many older browsers

Answer (score 1):

try this jsfiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/ArH5A/2/

i have updated my fiddle, you might want to uncheck `.chk_ignore_few` when you uncheck `#chk_ignore_few`

```
$(document).on("change", "#chk_ignore_all", function() {
if($(this).is(":checked"))
{
    $('.chk_ignore_few').each(function(k,fewChk){
      $(fewChk).prop('checked', true);
    });
}
else
{
    $('.chk_ignore_few').each(function(k,fewChk){
      $(fewChk).prop('checked', false);
    });
}
```

});

Comment: no success! I copy and pasted it in my code. nothing happend!

Comment: @phpGeek just wondering, is at least click event fired on your website? Are you waiting for element being in DOM before setting handler?

Comment: i would suggest $(document).on rather than binding event to checkbox

Comment: The click happens. I can see it with firebug. With breakpoint.

Comment: @phpGeek so reproduce your issue in a jsfiddle